# Why does inverse transformation work for deterministic number generators?

Tags: probability, sampling, monte-carlo

Given a random variable $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ we can set $X = F^{-1}(U)$ and conclude that $X$ has (assumed continuous) cdf $F$.  Indeed,
$$
P(X \leq x) = P(F^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(U \leq F(x)) = F(x).
$$

Note, in particular, that in the last equality we relied on the uniform distribution of $U$.  But, when we use a random number generator on a computer, it gives values in $[0,1]$ but does do deterministically; i.e., these values don't necessarily have the $Unif(0,1)$ distribution.  Even worse, quasi-random generators like the Halton sequence fill up the unit interval in a very specific order; points from these sequences are certainty not uniformly distributed.

So, why is it that we may still use the inverse transformation method on quasi-random numbers?  How does this guarantee a sample from cdf $F$?

Comment: As much as I know a pseudorandom generator still respects the property $P(U \leq y)=y$ so your equations still hold. You don't have $Cov(x_i, x_j)= 0$ and that will leave a correlation also in the modified distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you give, taken by itself, has nothing to do with
simulation. Your real questions involve doubts about the behavior
of the pseudo-random number generator.

When using PRNs from a generator, one assumes that for practical
purposes, they are not distinguishable from a sequence of independent
observations from $Unif(0,1).$

Of course generators vary in quality, but recent ones work very
well. The default PRN generator in R statistical software is 
the 'Mersenne twister', which produces a very large (Mersenne prime)
number of distinct values before the sequence repeats. It has been
vetted by subjecting it to a large battery of problems that are
known to have caused difficulties for previous generators. And there
are some other modern PRN generators that have good track records of working
well in simulations.

In the 1950's John von Neumann became frustrated with his early attempts
to generate PRNs with computer algorithms, and famously said that anyone
doing this was "living in a state of sin." So you are not the first
person to have such doubts.

Your assumption that the random variable $X$ in your equation must
be continuous is not exactly correct. If the quantile function 
(inverse CDF) of a discrete random variable is properly defined,
the equation still holds.

For example, there are better ways to simulate independent observations
from $Binom(n = 10, p = 1/2)$ than by using the quantile function, but
here is how that kind of simulation looks for 100,000 observations.
In R, the relevant quantile function is `qbinom(u, n, p)`. Values
`u` are from the Mersenne twister PRN generator.

```
n = 10;  p = 1/2
u = runif(10^5);  x = qbinom(u, n, p)
mean(x);  n*p
## 5.00871   # aprx E(X)
## 5         # exact E(X)
sd(x);  sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
## 1.58426   # aprx SD(X)
## 1.581139
hist(x, prob=T, br=(-1:10)+.5, col="skyblue")
i = 0:10;  pdf = dbinom(i, n, p)
points(i, pdf, pch=19, col="red")
```

The figure below shows a histogram of the simulated distribution of 
$X \sim Binom(10, .5);$ dots atop histogram bars show exact binomial
probabilities.

[image]

*Note:* There is a long history of increasingly successful attempts to
generate standard normal distributions. (The Box-Muller method is one of
them.) Even though the normal CDF
cannot be written in closed form, piecewise 'rational function approximations'
can come very close. Wichura has essentially inverted one of these
to get an approximation to the standard normal quantile function that
is about as accurate as can be represented in double-precision arithmetic.
So the current standard for algorithmic generation of random samples
from $Norm(0,1)$ seems to be to use the formula you show along with
Wichura's quantile function. This is the default method in R:

```
set.seed(1234); rnorm(1)
## -1.207066
set.seed(1234); qnorm(runif(1)) 
## -1.207066
```